# Ubuntu 16.04 booting to emergency mode after updating windows 8.1 to windows 10 in dual boot

Tags: boot, grub2, mode

I updated my windows 8.1 to Windows 10 and then the grub menu was not appearing, it directly booted to Windows 10, I tried in cmd with this code 
( bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Ubuntu\grubx64.efi )
It didn't work and then I installed Easy BCD
And it worked but when I try to load ubuntu it loads to emergency mode and I have tried systemctl reboot an systemctl default but again it opens in emergency mode. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you turned off fast boot in Windows 10. Windows 10 enables this setting by default, but this causes Ubuntu (in my system!) to boot into emergency mode.

It's available in the power settings of Windows 10.
I hope that helps you out!

Comment: Did that, it's still the same