# Boots to emergency mode after installing Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu, radeon

I know this is not the ideal order to install things, but I already had a working Kubuntu system and needed to add Windows. Once Windows was installed (took a while) I used a live Ubuntu to re-install the Grub menu. I get the menu, but when I boot to Kubuntu I get the pulsing logo for a while and then the screen below.

I tried the suggestion from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/792686/ubuntu-16-04-booting-to-emergency-mode-after-updating-windows-8-1-to-windows-10) of disabling Fast Boot in Windows, but it made no difference. I can boot into Windows with no problems.

If I hit enter I get a root prompt. I can run startx there and I get a UI minus the task bar. The error imply a graphics issue, but then graphics appear to be working. I assume Grub is not directly the issue as that can boot either system. I tried an older kernel, but that fails in the same way.

This is a home made desktop PC based on AMD A8-6500 with the built-in graphics. It has worked fine for years before this. Using 64 bit Kubuntu.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Try to boot with windows and then reboot and choose ubuntu. Always works for me.

Comment: That's how it should work, but choosing ubuntu (or Kubuntu in my case) always gives this error

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Had to reinstall and then it worked fine.

Comment: Mine was related to some windows disks being held onto. In windows "shutdown /s /t 5" fixed it so ubuntu booted

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution to this. I ended up doing a fresh Ubuntu install. I was able to use the existing /home, so a lot of settings were preserved